# Inconsistent Last Modified Coding of Excel Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there i have a code which ideally should store the time of which it was last modified for each of the sheets in the workbook. However this code which I have implemented seems pretty inconsistent and inaccurate. Sometimes it stores the time which i just visited the page, sometimes the code does not refresh as soon as i make an edition. Moreover, i have a running clock on cell A1 so it oftens overlaps written cells as well .Is there any improvement or alternative to the code? Thank you.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Index" Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = 0

    i = ActiveSheet.Index

    With Sheets("Index")

        .Cells(i, 1) = ActiveSheet.Name
        .Cells(i, 2) = Now

    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better if you con't use `ActiveSheet` but instead use the `Sh` parameter:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Sh.Name = "Index" Then Exit Sub

    i = Sh.Index

    With Sheets("Index")

        .Cells(i + 1, 1) = Sh.Name
        .Cells(i + 1, 2) = Now

    End With

End Sub
```

Technically you don't need to disable events, since the `Exit Sub` will prevent any loop.

Comment: it stills registers the time i visited the sheet and not modify